# QuickBooks (QBD) SyncActivity inconsistent behavior?

Tags: quickbooks, ipp-qbd-sync

I am using QuickBooks (QBD) SyncActivity API to get the information about Quickbooks Desktop synchronizations.But sometime when I call SyncActivity API I didn't get response and sometimes I get response.

Is there any connectivity issue with cloud or Is there anyting I'm missing to specify to get details from cloud, below is Request and code for more details,

```
    //Sync Activity details
    Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.SyncActivityRequest syncActivityRequest = new SyncActivityRequest();
    var syncStatuses = dataServices.GetSyncActivity(syncActivityRequest);
```

syncActivity Request,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SyncActivityRequest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2" />
```

Please share your views and suggessions.

Thanks,

Reshma D.

Answer (score 0):

You pass in a begin and end time stamp and you will get a response if there was any sync activity within the time span that you specified. There may or may not be something to return

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SyncActivityRequest xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2 RestDataFilter.xsd ">
  <OfferingId>ipp</OfferingId>
  <StartCreatedTMS>2011-06-02T08:31:25.0Z</StartCreatedTMS>
  <EndCreatedTMS>2011-06-02T08:31:28.0Z</EndCreatedTMS>
</SyncActivityRequest>
```

Thanks
Jarred